# Instanton numbers for diverse gauge bundles on diverse manifolds --- their relations to characteristic classes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, characteristic-classes, gauge-theory

It is standard (?) that the $SU(N)$ gauge theory has the instanton number $n$ quantized as $n \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$
n = { 1 \over 8\pi^2} \int_{\mathcal{M}_{4}}  \text{tr} \left(F \wedge F\right) = {1 \over 64 \pi^2} \int_{\mathcal{M}_{4}} d^4 x \,  \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\lambda} F_{\mu\nu}^\alpha F_{\rho\lambda}^\alpha
 \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

Here $F$ is the curvature 2-form $F=d A + A \wedge A$ and $A$ is the gauge 1-connection of the gauge bundle of gauge group $G$. Also $F=F^\alpha T^\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the Lie algebra indices, with repeated indices summed over.

We know that:

- If the gauge group is $G=SU(2)$, the instanton number $n \in \mathbb{Z}.$ I think this can be understood as
  $$
  n = c_2(V_{SU(2)}) \in \mathbb{Z}?
  $$
- If the gauge group is $G=SO(3)$ on the spin 4-manifold $\mathcal{M}_{4}$, then $n \in \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$. (I use the notation to mean that  $n \in \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$ as $n$ takes the half integer values.)
  $$
  n = p_1(V_{SO(3)})/4 \in \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}?
  $$
- If the gauge group is $G=SO(3)$ on the non-spin 4-manifold $\mathcal{M}_{4}$, then $n \in \mathbb{Z}/4$.
  $$
  n = p_1(V_{SO(3)})/4 \in \frac{1}{4}\mathbb{Z}?
  $$

What are the general statements we can make for other general $G$ and other manifolds?

Questions:

1. If the gauge group is $G=U(1)$, the instanton number $n \in 2 \mathbb{Z}.$ True or False? We can express this $n$ as the first Chern class $c_1$ square of associated vector bundle $V_{U(1)}$ as
   $$
   n = c_1(V_{U(1)})^2 \in 2 \mathbb{Z}?
   $$
   Is this correct?
2. If the gauge group is $G=SU(N)$, the instanton number $n \in \mathbb{Z}.$ True or False? We can express this $n$ as the second Chern class $c_2$ of associated vector bundle $V_{SU(N)}$ as
   $$
   n = c_2(V_{SU(N)}) \in \mathbb{Z}?
   $$
3. If the gauge group is $G=PSU(N)$ on the spin 4-manifold $\mathcal{M}_{4}$, the instanton number can be $1/N$ fractional of $\mathbb{Z}$ values:
   $$n \in  \frac{1}{N} \mathbb{Z},$$
   True or False?  What is the precise mathematical invariant to characterize this $n \in \frac{1}{N} \mathbb{Z}$? Is that Pontryagin class $p_1$  when $G=PSU(N)$ is real $\mathbb{R}$? Or some $c_2(V_{PSU(N)})$ when $PSU(N)$ is complex $\mathbb{C}$?
4. If the gauge group is $G=PSU(N)$ on the non-spin 4-manifold $\mathcal{M}_{4}$, the instanton number can be $1/N^2$ fractional of $\mathbb{Z}$ values: $$n \in  \frac{1}{N^2} \mathbb{Z},$$
   True or False?  What is the precise mathematical invariant to characterize this $n \in \frac{1}{N^2} \mathbb{Z}$? Is that Pontryagin class $p_1$  when $G=PSU(N)$ is real $\mathbb{R}$? Or some $c_2(V_{PSU(N)})$ when $PSU(N)$ is complex $\mathbb{C}$?
5. If the gauge group is $G=U(N)$ on the spin or non-spin 4-manifold $\mathcal{M}_{4}$, the instanton numbers carry both the $U(1)$ and $PSU(N)$ part with constraints. So there are two instanton numbers
   $n_{U(1)}$ and $n_{PSU(N)}$.
   What can be their constraints?
   $$n_{U(1)} \in \text{what characteristic class or invariant} ?$$
   $$n_{PSU(N)} \in  \text{what characteristic class or invariant}  ?$$

Comment: For $G = O(N)$ or $SO(N)$, we have $n = -\frac{1}{2}\int_Mp_1(E)$ where $E$ is a real (respectively orientable) vector bundle of rank $N$. For $G = U(N)$ we have $n = -\frac{1}{2}\int_Mp_1(E) = -\frac{1}{2}\int_Mc_1(E)^2 - 2c_2(E)$ where $E$ is a complex vector bundle of rank $N$, and for $G = SU(N)$ we have $n = -\frac{1}{2}\int_Mp_1(E) = \int_Mc_2(E)$ where $E$ is a complex vector bundle of rank $N$ with $c_1(E) = 0$.

Comment: For $G = PSU(N)$, one has natural projective bundles, but I don't know if you can get vector bundles in any natural way. You need a real vector bundle to talk about $p_1$ or a complex vector bundle to talk about $c_1$ or $c_2$. In particular, if you have a group homomorphism $PSU(N) \to O(M)$ or $U(M)$, then we can construct the associated vector bundle and talk about its Pontryagin or Chern classes.

Comment: many thanks @Michael Albanese! a systematic answer is still welcome

Comment: What would you consider a systematic answer to contain? Do you have references for the quantization in the $PSU(N)$ case?

Comment: No, Refs are welcome. I knew the Book by Freed and Uhlenbeck

Comment: I don't think they consider $PSU(N)$ in that book. Do you know that $n \in \frac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z}$ for $PSU(N)$ bundles over a spin manifold, or is that a guess? I only ask, because after stating it, you wrote "True or false?".

Comment: I guessed "∈(1/)ℤ  for () bundles over a spin manifold" - I am not sure how to prove it formally. Refs for proving them are welcome